# How to open multiple iTerm2 tab with admin privilege

Tags: terminal, applescript, command-line, bash, iterm

So I have an executable program in my `/usr/local/bin/` called `myApp`. I need to run multiple `myApp` processes in new `iTerm2` tabs with `sudo`.

The file structure is like this:

```
--myFolder
----v1
----v2
----v2
...
----vn
```

The work flow is like this:

```
1) `cd` into `myFolder`
2) open *new tab*

3) in *new tab*, `cd` into `v1`

4) `sudo myApp`

5) *enter my password*

6) *repeat for all vi*
```

The issue is that I need to be able to automate this process. I found a `osascript` to open new tabs [here](https://gist.github.com/vitalybe/021d2aecee68178f3c52), but I don't know how to have the newly opened tabs run `myApp` without asking my for password.

Answer (score 2):

The only way I can think of doing this is by setting up sudo to not require a password.  There are obvious security issues with this, but if those are acceptable in your situation, this is what I would do.

Edit the `/etc/sudoers` file with the `visudo` command:

`# sudo visudo`

Add a line at the bottom which grants the relevant user the ability to run any command as root without being prompted for a password (in this example `adam` is the user):

`adam ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL`

If you wanted a slightly more secure version, you could restrict them to only being able to run myApp without a password on a particular host (in this example the user is `adam`, the host is `hebe` and the only command they can run without a password is `/usr/local/bin/myApp`):

`adam hebe = (root) NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/myApp`